# Existing features not in Attribute Table and Data View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, editing

In ArcMap 10.7.1 I have drawn some lines in a already existing feature class containing other lines. The preexisting lines are displayed correctly in data view and attribute table. The new drawn lines are not shown either in attribute table and data view. If I guess the Object_Id of a new line and select by attribute, the line is displayed in data view and the table. But disappears immediately if unselected. Symbology is by categorie, unique values. Unique values are enabled. There is no definition query. Any body an idea?

I added this to screenshots. I hope this will clarify the issue. My question is, why are there lines which are shown only when selected?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the software you're working with by editing your question. How is the symbology of the layer you're working on?

Comment: Is the '<all other values>' checkbox enabled?  Did you add the unique values to the symbology rules?

Comment: If you have a definition query on your layer this could happen, as could the symbology suggestion already made.